# Evaluation of pre-operant & post-operant statement with another operator

Tags: java, operator-precedence

***EDIT: This is for my Java class. In class, my prof did a similar problem  and the answer he's expecting will most definitely be a number.***
***EDIT: (left to right), (right to left) is the associativity of operator***

```
int a = 3;
int b = a++ + ++a + a * 2 + ++a;
//So b = 24 & a = 6
```

I am uncertain to why this is the answer. My reasoning is:

```
int a = 3;
int b = a++ + ++a + a * 2 + ++a;
        (3) + (5) + (5 * 2) + (6)
        //a is 3, increments to 4 but stays as 3 [a++]
        //a is now 4 but increments to 5 [++a]
        //Since I'm evaluating left to right [a * 2] is [5 * 2]. This is because a holds the value 5.
        //a is 6 [++a]
```

Is my logic correct? Does the compiler evaluate it like this?
I understand that the order of precedence in terms of this question, where var is an arbitrary variable, goes like:

"post" -------------->   var++ & var--    (left to right)

"pre" --------------->   ++var & --var    (right to left)

"multiplication" ---->    * var  & var*     (left to right)

What is the general rule for stuff like this if instead we were taking the power, dividing, or modulating a variable in an expression like this?

Comment: No idea what is (left to right) still your logic about the quoted code is correct. If it was C then the result will be undefined but in `Java 8` it will be 24( 3 + 5 + 2 * 5 + 6).

Comment: @MadPhysicist When I print out a & b after the evaluation b prints 24 and a prints 6

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: No, it's not undefined. The JLS *does* specify an order.